# How to have two plots with different constant colour for scatter graph in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I'm using `pgfplots` and when I create a scatter graph with two sets of points based on data in a csv file, the colour of the markers varies with y axis value, which isn't what I want. I have two sets of points and would like blue markers and line for one, and red for the other - whilst this seems like a trivial issue I can't find any solution for it anywhere! Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
xmin=1, xmax=5, 
ymin=0, ymax=10,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
mark=*
]
\addplot[blue, mark=diamond*, scatter] table [x=a, y=e, col sep=comma] {Data/finaldata.csv};

\addplot[red, mark=square*, scatter] table [x=a, y=i, col sep=comma] {Data/finaldata.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
```

This is currently coming up with varying colour markers, is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 2):

That's just a standard line plot then, and not a scatter plot. If you want a basic scatter plot (i.e. no lines, just points) use the `only marks` key, i.e. `\addplot [only marks]...`. The `scatter` key that you used is for the case when you have essentially a third dimension that you want to visualize, and you can use color for that.

But all you need to do is to remove the `scatter` key, then you get a line with markers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
xmin=1, xmax=5, 
ymin=0, ymax=10,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[blue, mark=diamond*] table [x=a, y=e, col sep=comma] {
a,e
1,2
2,4
3,9
4,7
};

\addplot[red, mark=square*] table [x=a, y=i, col sep=comma] {
a,i
1,3
2,1
3,6
4,3
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used some dummy data because I of course don't have your data files.